# How to sort an array that has 3 values per row?

Tags: javascript

This is my array that I have to sort from highest average grade to lowest.

```
let students= [
         {name:"Petar", year:1, average:4.35},
         {name:"Ivana", year:1, average:3.88},
         {name:"Marko", year:2, average:2.27},
         {name:"Davor", year:2, average:4.15},
         {name:"Petra", year:3, average:3.99},
         {name:"Ivan", year:3, average:4.33},
         {name:"Goran", year:3, average:3.74}
     ];


students.sort(function(a,b){
         return a[1] - b[1];
     });
```

Comment: Those are not arrays but objects -> [Working with objects | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters `a` and `b` in `sort` function are objects and not array. Use `dot` to access the property of objects and not brackets.

```js
let students= [
    {name:"Petar", year:1, average:4.35},
    {name:"Ivana", year:1, average:3.88},
    {name:"Marko", year:2, average:2.27},
    {name:"Davor", year:2, average:4.15},
    {name:"Petra", year:3, average:3.99},
    {name:"Ivan", year:3, average:4.33},
    {name:"Goran", year:3, average:3.74}
];

const output = students.sort((a, b) => b.average - a.average);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Note sort mutates original and returns original so `output === students`

Comment: `sort()` mutates the orginal array use `students.slice(0).sort(....).map(x => ({...x}))`. 1)`slice()` to prevent mutating of original array. 2)`map()` to remove references and create a real copy.

Comment: @MaheerAli It depends on the needs of the reader in question. You might not find it troubling that the array is mutated. Also *slice* has a default first argument of `0`. - *"If `begin` is undefined, `slice` begins from index `0`."* - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Parameters)